# App window moves with each execution

Tags: display, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am relatively new to the Raspberry Pi and stumbled over a problem that I tried to search for, but don't know exactly how to look it up, to be honest.

Whenever I start a certain application (epson scan 2), the opening window moves a little bit up, so that I cannot reposition it or close it, other than from the status bar. I find it difficult to describe, so here is a video of the behavior: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/fDmRBuhpTDQ

I use a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Version 1.2

Current Raspberry OS installed (Debian Version 11.7)

Openbox version 3.6.1 installed

`apt-get update & apt-get upgrade` does not help.

Other windows do not show this problem (lxshell, geany, chromium, galculator, etc.)

To be frank, I don't know where to start, I am completely dumbfound by this problem. So even help in searching for this problem is greatly appreciated.

..::UPDATE 2023-09-16::..

I tried to use the openbox rc.xml for repositioning the window at the application startup.

I started the epson scan application and used 'top' to see how the process is named. It showed returned "epsonscan2". Then I ran 'obxprop | nano' but there was no mention of the epson window whatsoever.

I opened the rc.xml using

'sudo nano /etc/X11/openbox/rc.xml'

then I added:

```xml
<application>
  <application name="epsonscan2">
  <position force="yes">
    <x>center</x>
    <y>center</y>
  </position>
  </application>
</application>
```

I then restarted openbox with 'openbox --restart' but without success. Also a reboot of the Pi did not change anything in the windows behavior.

So I altered the .xml again to:

```xml
<application>
  <application class="*">
  <position force="yes">
    <x>center</x>
    <y>center</y>
  </position>
  </application>
</application>
```

my Idea was, that I would not care for every window to open in the center (the pi will serve as a scan server and is not used a lot). This did not work either.

Studying the rc.xml file, I have seen the alt+left mouseclick funtion to move the window. I can control it and we can work with the pi, but the problem remains unsolved for now.

Again, thank you for any hint or idea what to follow. I'll update anything else I will try.